# Print single field of an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, autocomplete

I am organizing the code to perform an autocomplete and search for users in a mysql table.

The query works but I have problems with the ajax code.
This is the code:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#search").keyup(function() 
    { 
        var inputSearch = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ inputSearch;
        if(inputSearch !== '')
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/search",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
                        $("#divResult").html(console.log(el.nome)).show();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return false;    
    });
});
```

I would like to ask someone more experienced than me how I can print from that array only the username field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#divResult").html(console.log(el.nome)).show();` -- what's going on here?

You want something more like:

```
success: function(data) 
{
    var resultHtml = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        resultHtml += el.nome +'<br />';
        // or, do away with resultHtml, just use:
        // $('#divResult').append(el.nome);
    });
    $("#divResult").html(resultHtml).show();
}
```

I find the `resultHtml`  approach more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to loop over your data:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        console.log(el.nome);
    });
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hycvvy24/)

Comment: First of all I thank you for the response. I tried the code but does not print

Comment: Any errors in the console? Where does it fail, on the server or on the client side? Are you actually receiving a response?

Comment: No, I checked. The function is executed. I think it's just the press that does not work properly. You place the code

Comment: Always returns the array, then the extraction work. I think I do something wrong when I see